# how to add text to openwysiwig editor by javascript code outside openwysiwig

Tags: javascript, openwysiwyg

I've got page to edit some html code from db, to do that I use openwysiwig http://www.openwebware.com/wysiwyg/demo.shtml which hosts over textarea, functions implemented in editor to insert images and hyperlinks aren't quite suitable for me, so I need to find some piece of code which help me to change/insert text to that area from outside the editor itself.

I've tried to find a solution but I could't find anything valuable; I've only learned that openwysiwig creates iframe over host textarea or something like that; besides that nothing what would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno why [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) got down~voted but it most certainly can do what you need. It has a very usable [javascript API](http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API) which allows you to insert elements into the editor area fairly easily. it integrates well with a wide variety of server tech also and includes a well designed plugin architecture for expansion.  Has a lot of support and sample code, and I've used it in tricky ajax-driven environments and am very happy with its capabilities. I can't find any usable Javascript api documents for openwysiwyg. You should be able to get FCK up and running in under an hour I would think

Comment: I gacen't realized that digg into element of page which holds edited conten swould be such a problem, and i haven't considered changing editing engine but fck is on GPL like license sho it will not be a problem, so it seems i should try my luck with fck, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very helpful perhaps, but something like tinymce or fckeditor is much better documented. I suggest changing.

Comment: i need to do such thing dinamically using javasctipt, the contents of tectarea are processed by open wyswig during initialization and probably it travels into some iframe which i want to get into

Comment: FCKeditor which I use has far more functionality and configuration options. You probably wouldn't need to hack it apart the way you are with this. 

Alternately, you could just process the data after it's posted to a page but before it's uploaded to the database.

Comment: Be more specific with the changes. Then I might be able to tell you.

Comment: simple i;be got a function in js  trigged by button which returns some text, and i'd like to puy/insert text into area of editor